# Cargar Javascript en misma ventana

Tags: javascript, ftp

Dentro de mi web tengo un formulario con javascript que me permite acceder a un servidor ftp. El código es el siguiente:

```
<script language="javascript">
function ftp_login(form) {
var login = form.login.value;
var clave = form.clave.value;
var servidor = form.servidor.value;
if (login && clave && servidor) {
var ftp_connect = "ftp://" + login + ":" + clave + "@" + servidor;
window.location = ftp_connect;
}
else {
alert("No fue posible la conexion!");
}
}
// -->
</script><FORM name=login>
  <table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="15%">Usuario:</td>
      <td width="85%"><input name="login" size="30"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password:</td>
      <td><input name="clave" type="password" size="30"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Servidor ftp://</td>
      <td><input name="servidor" size="30"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input name="button" type="button" onClick=ftp_login(this.form) value="conexion"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</FORM>
```

Cuando introduzco los datos, entra sin problema y me muestra los datos del ftp
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero esto me lo carga abriendo una ventana nueva. Me gustaría que lo cargase dentro del "marco de mi web". No se si me estoy explicando muy bien. Si alguien pudiera ayudarme. Gracias de antemano!!

Comment: si probas con `window.location.href = ftp_connect` ?

Comment: No funciona así tampoco :(